# mongodb indexing embedded fields (dot notation)

Tags: mongodb

Let's assume this is a document representing a customer.

```
{
    company_name: 'corporate ltd.',
    pocs: [
       {name: 'Paul', email: 'paul@corporate.com'},
       {name: 'Jessica', email: 'jessica@corporate.com'}
    ]
}
```

I wanted to define a unique index for `pocs.email`
So I issued the following command:

```
db.things.ensureIndex({"pocs.email": 1}, {unique: true})
```

The strange thing is that when trying to add another company with a poc having an email already exists in another company, mongo rejects that, respecting the unique index constraint.

that is, the following cannot exists:

```
{
    company_name: 'corporate ltd.',
    pocs: [
       {name: 'Paul', email: 'paul@corporate.com'},
       {name: 'Jessica', email: 'jessica@corporate.com'}
    ]
},
{
    company_name: 'contoso llc',
    pocs: [
       {name: 'Paul', email: 'paul@corporate.com'},
    ]
}
```

Which is fine. However, having duplicate poc within the same doc is possible, e.g.

```
{
    company_name: 'corporate ltd.',
    pocs: [
       {name: 'Paul', email: 'paul@corporate.com'},
       {name: 'Paul', email: 'paul@corporate.com'},
       {name: 'Jessica', email: 'jessica@corporate.com'}
    ]
},
```

see my cli commands sequence below:

```
> version()
version: 2.0.2
>
> use test
switched to db test
> db.test.ensureIndex({"poc.email": 1}, {unique: true})
> 
> db.test.insert({company: "contoso", poc: [{email: 'me@comapny.com'}]})
> db.test.insert({company: "contoso", poc: [{email: 'me@comapny.com'}]})
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.test.$poc.email_1  dup key: { : "me@comapny.com" }
> ({company: "contoso", poc: [{email: 'me.too@comapny.com'}, {email: 'me.too@company.com'}]})
> 
> 
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f44949685926af0ecf9295d"), "company" : "contoso", "poc" : [ { "email" : "me@comapny.com" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f4494b885926af0ecf9295f"), "company" : "contoso", "poc" : [ { "email" : "me.too@comapny.com" }, { "email" : "me.too@company.com" } ] }
```

Moreover, this happens either at `insert` or at `update`.

```
> db.test.update({"_id" : ObjectId("4f44949685926af0ecf9295d")}, {$push: { poc: {email: 'me@company.com'}}})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f4494b885926af0ecf9295f"), "company" : "contoso", "poc" : [ { "email" : "me.too@comapny.com" }, { "email" : "me.too@company.com" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f44949685926af0ecf9295d"), "company" : "contoso", "poc" : [        {       "email" : "me@comapny.com" },   {       "email" : "me@company.com" },   {       "email" : "me@company.com" } ] }
>
```

Is this a **bug** or a **by-design-feature** I missed spotting in the documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an open issue regarding the same problem [unique indexes not enforced within array of single document](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1068) . You can vote for it.

Also there is a nice workaround suggested by Kyle Banker in this similar post [Unique indexes on embedded documents](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/b9a88f3cb7232636)

**Update**

This is not only related to the embedded fields, we can reproduce the same for array fields too.

```
>db.uniqqueTest.insert({a:[1],x:1})
>db.uniqqueTest.createIndex({a:1}, {unique: true})
> db.uniqqueTest.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f44c6252434860b44986b02"), "a" : [ 1 ],"x":1 }
```

and it throws an error if we try to create a new document with the same value (correct behavior )

```
> db.uniqqueTest.insert({a:[1],x:3})
E11000 duplicate key error index: stack.uniqqueTest.$a_1  dup key: { : 1.0 }
```

But this works fine if we put the same value inside the array (no errors, silently accepts the duplicate value inside the array)

```
> db.uniqqueTest.insert({a:[2],x:2})
> db.uniqqueTest.update({x:2},{$push:{a:2}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f44c65f2434860b44986b05"), "a" : [ 2, 2 ], "x" : 2 }
```

But not for this

```
> db.uniqqueTest.update({x:2},{$push:{a:1}])
E11000 duplicate key error index: stack.uniqqueTest.$a_1  dup key: { : 1.0 }
```

Comment: +1. It is regarded as a bug, but a pretty weird one. "Unique indexes are designed to enforce only 1 document has that key.
Technically, that's true for this case, but in the way most people use the feature, they want unique to include the subdocs." I wonder if they can fix it, because it is a pretty big semantic change that might bite some people.

Comment: @Thilo, I totally agree with you. Its going to be a big change if they accepted it and totally contradicting the nature of what unique indexes supposed to be. Most people misunderstood the concept of embedded/sub document as a real document. Thats the real problem. But `embedded doc is  just  another field  (with nested properties) and only have the same features as the normal fields`. If they understand this,  these questions wont occur

Comment: @RameshVel perhaps it is a matter of point of view rather than [mis]understanding concepts. see, in case nested array has N items, there are now N entries in the index table, one per item. unlike "the nature of unique index" which create single entry per index definition per record.

More than that, if we are to take out sub documents and place them in a separate collection, than we are back to the join hell we know from classical RDBMS.

Comment: @RameshVel: I think it is reasonable to regard this as a bug. Unique should mean unique, even across multi-key fields in the same document. But it seems that no one thought about this before, the current behaviour has snug in, and changing it now is probably more trouble than living with it. We'll see how this turns out. Just watch the ticket. As for the discussion about embedded documents, do we know that this only happens with embedded documents? Does it not also happen with a simple top-level field? If so, this has nothing to do with embedded documents.